# What is equivalent of unsigned long of C in c#

Tags: c#, c

I have following variable in C

```
unsigned long crcTemp
```

What will be equivalent of it in C#

Comment: Did you look around on internet for this? Didn't any one tell you about data type `ulong`?

Comment: Can you please show how google failed to answer this?

Comment: Please check [ulong (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx).

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  Is C# `ulong` specified to be the same as C's `unsigned long`?  C's `unsigned long` is _at least_ 32-bits.  Does C# use such a variant definition for `ulong`?

Comment: `ulong` in C# is 64-bit unsigned integer while `uint` in C# is 32-bit unsigned integer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Since C's `unsigned long` is not specified to always be either of [those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730644/what-is-equivalent-of-unsigned-long-of-c-in-c-sharp#comment74525003_43730644), perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43730674/2410359) answer suffices.

Comment: It is the same  information in the link which I shared. I don't see any difference.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Agree. Your comment (http://stackoverflow.com/a/43730674/2410359) addresses only the C# side of the issue.  The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43730674/2410359) bare addresses the C side of the question with "it is uint or ulong".  Yet that answer is better than the misleading accepted one.

Comment: I am not getting the point here.... Size wise `unsigned long` of C and `uint` of C# are same. That can be the answer of the question here. By name `unsigned long` of C and `ulong` of C# are same but`ulong` offers wider range then `unsigned log`. The answer is not posted by me and I am not sure which way it is `misleading`. The answer explains that the `uint` and `unsigned long` are of the same size which is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143212/discussion-between-chux-and-chetan-ranpariya).

Comment: ...and yet Google led me here.

Answer (score 5):

it is `uint` or `ulong` in `c#`.

- `uint` for 32 bits
- `ulong` for 64 bits.

For Example

```
uint myUint = 4294967290; 
ulong uLong = 9223372036854775808;
```

More details, please refer [uint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx) and [ulong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx)

Comment: This answer is at least partial correct in that it takes into account C's `unsigned long` bit width is not specified to one value.  C's `unsigned long` is at least 32 bit.  On rare machines, it may not be neither 32 nor 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

> Unsigned integer

Reason:  "unsigned long " in C language contains 4 bytes/0 to 4294967295 and same way the Unsigned integer in C# contains 0 to 4294967295."

So this might be helpful to you.

Comment: `unsigned long` range in C is _at least_ 0 to 4294967295.  It may be wider.    When it is wider, this is an incorrect answer.